# how to change $\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_i^TAu_i$ to matrix form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, numerical-methods

I have the following expression:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_i^TAu_i$, where $u_i\in R^{k \times 1}$, $A \in R^{k \times k}$. Here $u_i$ is one row of $U \in R ^ {n \times k}$, I would like to know how to change the following expression to matrix form? what is the trick to change summation format to matrix format, easily?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_i^TAu_i$$

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is an easier way to phrase it using the matrix $U$, as a matrix-matrix product always yields another matrix, and trying to get a $1 \times 1$ matrix won't work in the general case I'm afraid.

Comment: $\textrm{trace}(U^T A U)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such situations it is often helpful to use the trace and especially its cyclic property $tr(ABC)=tr(CAB)$.
$$
\sum u_i^TAu_i=\sum tr(u_i^TAu_i)=\sum tr(Au_iu_i^T)=tr(A\sum u_iu_i^T).
$$
Depending on your purpose you then replace the sum by $V$ with the defining property that it is positive semi-definite, or with $UU^T$ where $U$ is the matrix with the $u_i$ as columns.